# Pandas DataFrame - split rows into n windows, shift windows by m elements, find average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, the column contains (for example) 30 rows, you need to split them into windows of 5 elements, shift each window by 4 elements relative to the other window and find the average value along the row.
There should be 10 lines left.
The number of lines and the size of the window can be arbitrary.
Is there some kind of mechanism for shifting windows and calculating values in pandas?.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiYpm.png)

Answer (score 0):

example solution from @CrazyElf

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': [i + j + i / 10 for i in range(6) for j in  range(1, 6)]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame([[df.iloc[j + i * 4, 0] if i - 1 < j < i + 5 else pd.NA       for i in range(6)] for j in range(10)])
new_feature_mean = df_new.sum(axis=1) / (~df_new.isna()).sum(axis=1)
```